# What is fracture toughness and how is it different from the strength of a material?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, material-science

Strength is just the amount of force that an object can take before breaking, so what is fracture toughness?

Comment: Fracture is a term that can include impact tests, and is usually geared more toward a end product.  In some cases a fracture test result may include ultimate tensile strength.  On the flip side, a strength may not be looking for fracture but a different condition (such as .2% yield strength)

Comment: "Resistance to fracture" here is a loaded term. It could mean different things depending on context. If it's referring to impacts and not constant load, then it is talking about to elongation before yielding. This is basically the amount of energy it can absorb, since impacts are energy based rather than force based. Or it could mean something completely different like cracks not propagating very far before being stopped.

Comment: Ok thanks! I think it is also referred too as fracture toughness in the book I am reading!

Comment: Toughness is a much more meaningful word than "fracture resistance".

Comment: What book/ What reference?

Comment: Materials Science and Engineering An Introduction by William D. Callister, Jr., David G. Rethwish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fracture toughness is a measure of the amount of applied work required to initiate a crack in a test sample and then "walk" it all the way across the sample cross-section, so as to tear the sample in two.

In this type of test the load is applied suddenly by smacking the test sample with a heavy hammer rather than by gradually pulling the sample apart until it breaks, as in a tensile strength test.

The standard impact toughness test is called the *Charpy impact test*.